# HTML Unordered List not working

Tags: html, css, list

So I've been creating a webpage and tried to use an unordered list but it doesn't work and just appears with a grey background as a single string.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    li {
      float: left;
    }
    
    li a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li a:hover {
      background-color: #111;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="project file 1.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>My Project
  </title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="nav">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="project.html">Home Page
                   </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="projectpage.html">Project Page
                   </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="cvpage.html">CV page
                    </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="contactpage.html">Contact Me
                    </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <h1>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <header>
      <h1>
        <U> Home 
              <span style="color:red">Page
              </span>
            </U>
      </h1>
    </header>

    <!--navigation bar -->

    <div class="box one">
      <h2>
        <U>Hobbies
            </U>
      </h2>

      <p>These are just a few of hobbies but these are the ones that take up the most time
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>Football</li>
        <li>Rugby</li>
        <li>Cycling</li>
        <li>Gaming</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--profile  -->
    <div class="box two">
      <h2>
        <U>Photo Of Me
            </U>
      </h2>
      <p>Please don't be mean
      </p>
      <img src="ProfilePic.jpg" alt="Profile pic" width="300" height="300">
      <p>I know what a beautiful man ;)
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box three">
      <!-- Jobs table -->
      <h2>
        <u>Table Of My Current/ Previous Jobs
              </U>
      </h2>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>company
          </th>
          <th>Job Title
          </th>
          <th>length of time there
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Network Research
          </td>
          <td>Telemarketer
          </td>
          <td>2 Months
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>David MacBeth Moir
          </td>
          <td>Kitchen Associate
          </td>
          <td>3 months
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Justice Mill
          </td>
          <td>Kitchen Associate
          </td>
          <td>1 year to present
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!-- spoons para-->
      <h3>
        <U>Why I Stay at Spoons
            </U>
      </h3>
      <p>Cause its good patter and the people there as a good laugh but he job its self is pretty rubbish
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box four">
      <h2>
        <U>Questions?
            </U>
      </h2>
      <p>Please feel free to ask any questions if you need help understanding anything for example:
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>Information given didnt make sense
        </li>
        <li>Further questions on the information on the page
        </li>
        <li>The layout was confusing
        </li>
        <li>ect...
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Please leave a comment...
          </legend>
          <label for="name">Name:
              </label>
          <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
          <label for="email">Email
              </label>
          <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
          <label for="comments">Comments
              </label>
          <textarea name="comments" cols="45" rows="5">
              </textarea>
          <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box5">
  </div>
  <div class="box6">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried to create unordered lists in boxes 1 and 4 but they don't display correctly, main CSS spreadsheet is as follows:

```
h1 {
    color:black;
        }
     h2 {
        text-align:center;
    }
     p {
        margin-top:10px;
    }

    *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
    body {
    background-color: white;
    }
    form {
    padding-top:120px;
    }
    img {
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:6px;
    border: 3px solid grey;
     }
    h3 {
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-top:10px;
    }
    h4 {
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-top:40px;
     }
     iframe {
    margin-left:150px;
    margin-top:40px;
    }
     #wrapper{
     width:1000px;
    height:1350px;
    margin:auto;
    background:#white;  
    }
    #nav{
    width:1000px;
    height:50px;
    background:grey;
    }
    .box{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
    background:#ff0;
    margin: 65px 0 0 65px ;
    border:5px solid grey;
    } 
    .box2 {
    width: 400px;
    height:900px;
    float:left;
    background:#ff0;
    margin:65px 0 0 65px;
    border:5px solid grey;
    }
    .box3 {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    float:right;
    background:#ff0;
    margin-right:65px;
    margin-top:65px;
    border:5px solid grey;
    }
    .box4 {
    width:865px;
    height:400px;
    background:#ff0;
    margin-left:65px;
    margin-top:540px;
    border:5px solid grey;
    }
    .box5 {
    width:auto;
    height:150px;
    background:white;
    }
    .box6 {
    width:auto;
    height:60px;
    background:#3c3c3c;
    }
    .box7 {
    width:auto;
    height:1100px;
    background:white;
    }
    .one p{
    color:red;
    }
    .two p{
    color:purple;
    }
    .three p{
    color:green;
    }
    .four p{
    color:red;
    }
```

I cannot understand why the unordered list isn't working and I've checked it with a couple friends who have coded HTML before and they can't offer me any help. I thought that it could perhaps have been the div that goes around the list but I can't see anything that would mess with the actual list. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create an [mcve]! Most of the code you've included appears to be irrelevant. Click the `<>` icon in the editor and make a live demo.

Comment: Why are you using float at all in your boxes?

Answer (score 1):

You used:

```
li {
    float: left;
}
```

Basically you can't float `li` items if you want them to work properly. Target your `li` items which you want to `float` through classes, id-s, or html tags, but not directly.